# ArrayAdapter wont load string from another activity

Tags: android, arrays, listview, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to send data of a List Array to an Array Adapter in another activity. This is based arround a smiple counter app that when i open the second activity it shows which buttons have been pressed and how many times.

So far i have created my array list the first activity

```
String player1data = lifepointsP1.getText().toString();
            ArrayList<String> myList1 = new ArrayList<String>();
            myList1.add(player1data);
```

and this updates everytime the lifepointsP1 text is changed. Then on the button pushed to open the new activity i do this:

```
Intent mi = new Intent(v.getContext(), MatchHistory.class);
            mi.putExtra("p1L", myList1);
            startActivity(mi);
```

which sends the data across to the second activity and i retrieve it like this:

```
String p1List = (getIntent().getStringExtra("p1L"));
```

i then create my array adapter and insert that string as the value:

```
lvP1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvP1R);
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MatchHistory.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, p1List);
    lvP1.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

although, this then gives me an error and tells me to take out the 'p1List' string out of the arrayadapter parameters. i dont know why it is doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As other mentioned you are using wrong data type to get the extra from intent.

Replace this line:

```
String p1List = (getIntent().getStringExtra("p1L"));
```

With:

```
ArrayList<String> p1List = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("p1L");
```